# How to dynamically change CSS style attribute of DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, css

We have a div tag:  `<div id='div1' style="background-color:red"></div>`

I would like to know how can we change the style attribute of this div tag:-

1. Can we clear the style value?
2. Can we append value to the existing style attribute ?
3. Can we set new value to style attribute

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125453/modifying-css-class-property-values-on-the-fly-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: I would like to have something like document.getelementbyid (chagne the property)

Comment: Use the .style property all HTML nodes have.

Comment: you can use addclass or removeclass of jquery

Comment: This is about style attribute, other one was about class attribute..

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript modify style of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458425/javascript-modify-style-of-an-element)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var div = document.getElementById('div1');

// Clear Value
div.setAttribute('style','');
  // OR
div.removeAttribute('style');

// Set Style / Append Style
div.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
```

Don't modify the style attribute directly when adding or changing styles unless you want to remove them all.

JavaScript removeAttribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.removeAttribute
Javascript Style: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style

Answer (score 2):

Use `setAttribute()` to override and add new value over the property.

```
var div = document.getElementById('div1');
// div.setAttribute('property', 'value');

div.setAttribute("style", "color: green; align:center;");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add style this way  using js -

```
document.getElementById('#div1').style += "padding-top:40px";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, for example:

```
$("#div1").css("property",'value');
```